# How to set the Classpath to include all JAR files in a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, classnotfoundexception

I am using the following in a batch file

```
set CLASSPATH=%XX_LIB%\commons-collections-3.1.jar;XX_LIB%\paz-basic.jar;%XX_LIB%\paz-common.jar;%XX_LIB%\per.jar

set CLASSPATH=%XX_LIB%;%XX_HOME%\classes;%CLASSPATH%
REM set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%

set PR_CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%
```

There are multiple class files present in the per.jar file. But when I am executing the batch file only the main class which is mentioned below, is getting executed for the rest of the classes it is giving `CLASSNOTFOUND exception` in the log file,

`"%EXECUTABLE%"//IS//%SERVICE_NAME% --StartClass com.ance.paz.common.per.xouper.ServiceMain`

Please suggest. Should javac be used along with the CLASSPATH?

Comment: Consider including a manifest in your application's jarfile and setting the Main-Class and Class-Path.  Then you'll be able to run your application with `java -jar MyApp.jar`

Answer (score 0):

If what you pasted above is a true copy of your exact batch file, it would appear that you are missing a `%` in the 1st line establishing `CLASSPATH`

```
set CLASSPATH=%XX_LIB%\commons-collections-3.1.jar;%XX_LIB%\paz-basic.jar;%XX_LIB%\paz-common.jar;%XX_LIB%\per.jar
```

notice the additional `%` preceding the 2nd usage of `XX_LIB`